# Chess move validation library for ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript, chess

Do you know any chess move validation library for ActionScript 3 ?
I have searched in google but I can not find anything.
Please tell me if you know.

If there isn't any library, I think that I have to port from Java to AS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd just write it because it is going to end up very tightly bound to your game/position representation.

Think about it: ust legal moves, or move validation in game context (50-move rule, 3-time repeated position, en-passant, promoted pieces, castling availability...?).

You might even have to pass the entire move history for the game.

It is not that much work if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/osas3cf/updates/list

That one has code included for a chess move validator. Check it out

Comment: Is using java ok from inside actionscript?